# Chat homepage logo hard to read

Tags: bug, chat, design, logo

[On the site page of the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&sort=active&host=chat.stackexchange.com) the logo of StackExchange is hard to read:

[image]

If you look close, you see that there is a logo, but you need to loop very close to read it. I suggest we add a border to the logo, so we increase the contrast:

[image]

*Sorry for poor image quality, I am not good with freehand line drawing*

Comment: Your FHRC is just fine, cheers!

Comment: +1 for freehand.  We have to support the ancient memes, lest they wither and die, forgotten fruit of amusements past.